# How to solve Alligation and mixture shortcut

Tags: real-analysis

How much water must be added to $60$ litres of milk at $1.5$ litres for Rs. $20$ so as to have a mixture worth Rs.$10 \frac{2}{3}$ a litre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that water is free and $x$ liter water is required

the price of $60$ liter milk is $\displaystyle60\cdot\frac{20}{1.5} \ \ \ \  (1)$  RS.

Now we have diluted milk of $60+x$ liter with rate $\displaystyle=\frac{10}{\dfrac23}$ RS./liter

So, the total price will be
$\displaystyle (60+x)\frac{10}{\dfrac23}$ which must be same as $(1)$

Comment: Thank you so much for spending your valuable time...